# pygame + pyBox2D -- torque?

Tags: python, pygame, box2d

I'm currently trying to write a bit of a physics simulator using Box2D and a pygame frontend. However, it seems like there is no torque being properly applied to any bodies in my program, and I'm not really sure why. Using this sample program:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import pygame
import Box2D as b

def main():
    pygame.init()
    pygame.font.init()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((600, 450))
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()

    running = True

    world = b.b2World()
    world.gravity = (0, -5)
    ground = world.CreateStaticBody(
            position=(0,-5), shapes=b.b2PolygonShape(box=(60,5)))
    obj = world.CreateDynamicBody(
            angle=15, position=(30,22), shapes=b.b2PolygonShape(box=(5,5)))

    while running:
        screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
        events = pygame.event.get()
        if any(map(lambda e:e.type == pygame.QUIT, events)):
            running = False

        drawPolygons(screen, obj)

        world.Step(1/60, 10, 10)
        pygame.display.flip()
        clock.tick(60)
    pygame.quit()


def drawPolygons(screen, body):
    for fixture in body.fixtures:
        shape = fixture.shape
        vertices = [body.transform*v * 10 for v in shape.vertices]
        vertices = [(v[0], 450-v[1]) for v in vertices]
        pygame.draw.polygon(screen, (255,255,255), vertices)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

If I run this, the angled square will drop to the floor and just sit at an angle instead of tipping over. Similarly, applying a force to a point other than the object's center will act as if I'm applying to the center. Am I missing something?

EDIT: The body won't rotate even if I explicitly apply a torque using the ApplyTorque method, so I'm reasonably sure that it's a problem with the way my fixtures are set up, or maybe how I'm drawing them. Applying forces otherwise works as intended, so I'm not quite sure what's going wrong.

EDIT2: After further experimentation, it seems that nothing short of setting the angular velocity manually will affect the angular velocity of my body, which is really strange (ApplyTorque doesn't touch it)

Comment: What's the density of the dynamic body that you want to be able to apply torque to? Maybe you need to set that? The density effects the mass and rotational mass of dynamic bodies. If the density was say 0, then the system will think that the body has infinite mass in which case applying torque won't do much.

Comment: It turns out I forgot to include any actual fixture definitions, whoops! Thanks for making me double check, this has been driving me insane.